# Is it possible to compute a 2D-FFT if the input size is not a power of 2?

Tags: fft, dft

Let us suppose to have an image with size $28\times28$, and that we want to apply a 2D-FFT without any padding operation. Does exist any algorithm which allows to perform the 2D-DFT calculation with time complexity $O\big(N \log_2(N)\big)$?

Comment: Of course.  An $N \times N$ 2D FFT is nothing other than performing $N$ 1D FFTs on each row, followed by performing $N$ FFTs on each column.  But the complexity is then $O\big( N^2 \log_2(N) \big)$.

Comment: So, it is possible to perform also a 1-D FFT for arbitrary lengths which are not power of two, right?

Comment: @GiorgioBianchi - Yes, there are efficient FFT algorithms for arbitrary lengths. Bluestein's algorithm rewrites an FFT problem as a convolution problem, which can then be zero-padded to a more convenient size, solved using a power-of-two FFT/IFFT and the result is then cropped back to the original size.

Comment: Not that I have their code, but [FFTW](https://www.fftw.org/) was, at least a quarter century ago, considered the Fastest FFT in the West.  For any length $N$.  Dunno if they still are.

Comment: They're doing well, @robertbristow-johnson, though their benchmarking suite is completely broken, and relies on just skipping the things that fail acting as if that wasn't a problem. Massive problem of missing investment in maintenance :(

Comment: Oh and their fft is fast for any number that can be factored into small prime factors. I think it depends on the way it was built which factors are available, but iirc up to 11 was fine by default on Debian builds.